# Casting video to Chromecast from browser using angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, chromecast

I'm developing a media player in angular and I would like to be able to cast my videos from my browser to my android tv.

I can already do it on Android from a Chrome browser who shows me the cast button on the upper left corner of my video.

But I searched and I can't find a way to trigger the cast myself.

Netflix appear to be able to do it in a browser so it must be possible.

Does anyone knows the way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out the Chrome Cast API? https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/

Comment: I was looking for a multi browser solution but an extension for Firefox who support this API got released. Thanks :)

Comment: @JacquesKRAMP Can you please tell me how did you manage to make the Chromecast work in Angular? I am trying to achieve the same functionality with media element js player but it's not working. It is working fine in a simple HTML5.